# DFS to check if characters exist on diagonals in 2d grid

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

I'm writing an algorithm to check if a 2D array has a sequence of characters. My algorithm is working for horizontal and vertical searches but not working for diagonals:

```
board = [
    ['Z', 'B', 'N', 'O', 'N', 'O'],
    ['Z', 'B', 'O', 'N', 'N', 'Z'],
    ['B', 'O', 'B', 'B', 'N', 'B'],
    ['O', 'N', 'O', 'N', 'N', 'N'],
    ['Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'B', 'O'],
    ['B', 'Z', 'O', 'Z', 'B', 'N']
]

def dfs(board, word):
    if not board:
        return False
    N,M = len(board), len(board[0])
    stack = []
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
            if board[i][j] == word[0]:
                stack.append((i,j,0,{(i,j)}))
    while stack:
        i,j,step,visit=stack.pop()
        step+=1
        if step==len(word):
            return True        
        for (ni,nj) in [(i+x,j+y) for x,y in [(0,1), (0, -1), (1,0), (-1,0)]]:
            if (ni,nj) not in visit and 0<=ni<N and 0<=nj<M and board[ni][nj] == word[step]:
                stack.append((ni,nj,step,visit.union({(ni,nj)})))
    return False
```

My function `DFS` should return True for inputs `ZZZZ`, `NNNN` and `OOOO` but `OOOO` is not working - diagonal steps are not working.

[image: expected result]

How can I solve it?

Comment: You have only one case to solve (like diagonals starting from upper left part) as all other three could be visited by the same algorithm and just mirroring your board either left-right, up-down, or both. And you may be able to restrict further based on the length of the string searched (I have seen this example based on TicTacToe asked for during interviews)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
for (ni,nj) in [(i+x,j+y) for x,y in [(0,1), (0, -1), (1,0), (-1,0)]]:
```

only considers neighbors to be the four cardinal directions. To include diagonals, we should have 8 neighbors:

```
directions = [
    (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), 
    (-1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1), (1, -1)
]

for ni, nj in [(i + x, j + y) for x, y in directions]:
```

After the modification, diagonals are explored by the algorithm:

```
print(dfs(board, "OOOO")) # => True
print(dfs(board, "NBNZ")) # => True
print(dfs(board, "BNZO")) # => True
```

---

If you plan to limit the search to straight directions (eliminating something like `"ZBOB"` from the top left), the DFS approach won't be terribly helpful. You can simply iterate from each square in all possible directions without making any turns, bailing early on the first non-matching letter. Your current algorithm permits turns, even without the diagonal modification, so I'm assuming you'd like to preserve this permissive logic.

Comment: Man, you are a monster! :D
Is possible to perform a search using multiple words? Right now, I'm doing a loop for each word

Comment: Hmm, there might be an optimal way to do it, but it might not really be worth the effort on such a small grid. Premature optimization and all that. Until you hit performance issues, I'd just loop over all the words you want to check and DFS the grid for each one of them. Can you use letters more than once between words? Of course, if you have a million words you want to check on a huge grid, that'd probably require some thinking (and opening up a special question for it).

Comment: Hold a second, let me explain what I mean: is possible to find any combination of same 4 letters in any direction? And how many combinations has? I mean that I want to know how many combinations of four letters exists in matrix.

Comment: Sure, seems doable, but there's still uncertainty as far as the requirements go. Is it OK for "any direction" to include bends or does it have to be straight? Can letters in the grid be re-used more than once (both for one word and between words)? How important is performance (e.g. is the grid huge?). It's a far cry from what you're asking above, so I'd take a shot at it yourself, and if you run into problems, open a new question. I'll try to take a look at it and help if you wind up doing so. A place to start might just be `itertools.combinations` and using the existing DFS in a loop.

Comment: Great! I'll take a look into itertools.combinations!

Comment: Performance is not important. I just want to count how many sequence of 4 letters exists in matrix. In my example, should return a count of 3

Comment: In your example, you might need to avoid DFS like I mentioned in my answer, because I think you'll get a much higher count than 3 on `"NNNN"` and `"ZZZZ"` due to the diagonals and the ability to re-use letters. You'll need to mark squares as used on the grid after each run of the DFS, so it's a bit tricky. First decide whether the algorithm should be "Boggle"-style or "Connect 4"-style, that is, lines can curve or must be straight. It sounds to me like you want "Connect 4" without reuse (otherwise you'd get 2 for both left-to-right and right-to-left on `"ZZZZ"` and same for `"NNNN"` up/down).